# How can you use imagemin with WebJars from Clojure?

Tags: clojure, ring, webjars, imagemin

As far as I can tell [WebJars](http://www.webjars.org/documentation) are designed to serve up static assets from a JVM based back end. There is a WebJar library for [imagemin](https://github.com/webjars/imagemin), but imagemin is a build time or run time concern. The browser has no idea what to do with gifsicle.exe or the like.

So how can imagemin be used from a JVM based language, specificially Clojure in my case?

Comment: You will need an asset pipeline for this - like sbt-web.  But I'm not sure if one exists for Clojure / leiningen.

Comment: @JamesWard, looks like there are at least two asset pipeline implementations for Clojure: https://github.com/alxlit/venturi and https://github.com/mylesmegyesi/conveyor. Venturi has a webjars plugin which sounds promising. Hopefully it doesn't utilize the clj-v8 dependency since that lacks Windows support. If I try this I'll report back what I find.